# How do I take data from one csv file and find the results in another using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have two csv files with data in both of them. The first one has columns of data like the following:
[image: CSV File]

And the second csv file looks like this
[image: CSV File2]

What I want to do is able to group these together based on the values in column D. I want to create a new column next to D that matches its value to the detail in the second file. The output would look something like:
[image: Output]

File number 1 is always changing numbers and there are hundreds of numbers in each file so I don't want to write them manually in a list for the code.

Comment: To do csv processing in Python, I recommend looking into pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: use `merge()` function of pandas module to merge both the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('first_file.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('second_file.csv')

df1['Details'] = df1['D'].map(df2.set_index('Number')['Details'])
# or
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='D', right_on='Number', how='left')

df1.to_excel('merge_file.csv', index=False)
```

**Update**: the same version with `csv` module:

```
import csv

with (open('first_file.csv') as fp1,
      open('second_file.csv') as fp2,
      open('merge_file.csv', 'w') as out):
    df1 = csv.DictReader(fp1)
    df2 = csv.DictReader(fp2)
    mapping = {row['Number']: row['Details'] for row in df2}
    dfm = csv.DictWriter(out, df1.fieldnames + ['Details'])
    dfm.writeheader()
    for row in df1:
        dfm.writerow(dict(row, Details=mapping.get(row['D'], '')))
```

Output:

| A | B | C | D | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 22 | 13 | 41 | comma |
| 52 | 36 | 67 | 87 | carrer |
| 91 | 150 | 41 | 12 | recording |
| 123 | 14 | 76 | 16 | mold |

Comment: I am getting a utf-8 codec error but I think thats a issue with my file but the code looks good!

Comment: You can also provide `encoding='utf-8'` as parameter of `open` function.